# HTML5 Geolocation not working anymore

Tags: html, geolocation

We have a page that uses html5 geolocation, which seemed to stop working early this morning for desktop users of Firefox and Google Chrome, but IE9 still seems to work.  If I am on a wireless laptop/device it works fine.  If I go to a desktop computer using ethernet, and try with Firefox or Google Chrome, it will ask me if I want to allow the browser to share my location, and I click Yes, the browser doesn't to anything.  If I do the same thing with IE9, it locates me fine.  This was working fine yesterday, and seems to have stopped working around 1:00 AM EST.  Any ideas or suggestions?

thanks!

Comment: Post some code? Cut things down to a minimal test case? Right now, we're just having to guess what your page does

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with our code, as we have tried various other sites from a desktop with firefox and chrome, and the geolocation doesn't work on these sites either.  For example, if we go to http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp and click the "try it" button, it doesn't work.  If we go to http://www.starbucks.com/store-locator and click the Share Location button, it doesn't locate us.  I see that firefox and chrome both use the Google Location Services API, could they have changed something that doesn't work with desktop browsers anymore??

Comment: Possibly, but in that case it's not really a software development related question and so off topic for here.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with the latest version of Chrome (33.0.1750.154 m).  It started happening to me as well.

[Here's the documented issue.](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=154096)  Scroll down to the latest entries.

> Today (18 minutes ago)
>
> Yesterday geolocation on Chrome Version 33.0.1750.152 was working fine.  Now, navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( successCallback, errorCallback ) is always triggering errorCallback when running on localhost.  Getting the following error: PositionError {message: "Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : Returned error code 404.", code: 2, PERMISSION_DENIED: 1, POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: 2, TIMEOUT: 3}.

Answer (score 0):

The cause is that, to enhance user privacy, Google Chrome and most other browsers now require SSL/TLS (http**s**://, *not* http://) with at least a self-signed certificate before they will allow `getCurrentPosition` or `watchCurrentPosition` to return any results. No error visible to the user is generated if unencrypted http:// is used — it just returns empty results (some browsers may indicate a “Blocked” error in the JavaScript Debugging Console, but that’s only visible in the Developer Tools). Chrome was one of the first to do this, but now nearly all modern browsers do likewise.

Install a free GetEncrypt certificate (or full certificate if desirable for uses such as eCommerce) on your server and force SSL on at least that page, and it should work. Self-signed can be used for test purposes only and will generate a browser security alert that must be bypassed.